# Bootstrap issue, messing with my own custom navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need help on a bootstrap issue. I have a custom navbar that is added to each page by a header.php file. This file contains all my nav info. The problem I'm getting is that when I add the bootstrap CDN to a page, the following happens to my navbar and I can't quite figure out why. Can someone help me with this problem.

[Nav bar before bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkvMD.png)

[navbar before bootstrap hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH5f4.png)

[navbar after bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7Mua.png)

[navbar after bootstrap hover effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Rj3.png)

Comment: We need code please. Edit your question to include a [mcve]. We can't possibly be expected to help you with just images

Answer (score 1):

Please check your code as you are trying to use bootstrap it may have override your CSS which have used earlier. 
 1. You have completely style your navbar with bootstrap or
 2. avoid your code to be overridden from bootstrap css

Comment: Thanks this helped me take care of it. Looks like one of the classes were similar and it was overwriting it. Appreciate it